# Alterar o valor da label a partir de uma lista

Tags: javascript

Oi, sou iniciante em javascript, preciso de uma ajuda: Preciso que altere o valor de uma label em função de um item selecionado em uma lista:

por exemplo:

selecionado item 1 ---- o valor da label deve ser 1,00
selecionado valor 2 ----- o valor da label deve ser 2,00

abaixo o código e desde ja obrigado

Lista

```
<div class="lista_serv">
    <form action="">
        <span>
            <label>Selecione o produto | serviço:</label> 
                <select class="form-control" id="lista_servicos">
                        <option name="selecione" value="0">Selecione</option> 
                        <option name="gracco" value="49.55">XGracco</option>
                        <option name="automacao" value="0.051">Automação</option>
                        <option name="ia" value="0.761">IA</option>
                        <option name="triare" value="2.418">Finch Flow</option>
                        <option name="esteiras_usuarios" value="41.210">Esteiras por usuário</option>
                        <option name="esteiras_processos" value="1.628">Esteiras por processo</option>
                        <option name="publicacoes" value="0.426">BPO Publicações</option>
                        <option name="cadastro" value="2.02">BPO Cadastro</option>
                        <option name="oficios" value="5.98">BPO Ofícios</option>
                </select>
        </span>
</form>
</div>


label a ser alterada

<div class="c_unit">
    <label>Custo Unitário: <b class="custo_un">R$</b><label class="vlr_tab_serv" name="serv_selecionado"><b class="custo_un" id="" value="">**0,00**</b></label></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Da uma olhada nas mudanças a seguir:

```js
function updateField(){

let selecionado = document.getElementById('lista_servicos').value;

document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = selecionado;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista_serv">
    <form action="">
        <span>
            <label>Selecione o produto | serviço:</label> 
                <select class="form-control" id="lista_servicos" onchange="updateField()">
                        <option name="selecione" value="0">Selecione</option> 
                        <option name="gracco" value="49.55">XGracco</option>
                        <option name="automacao" value="0.051">Automação</option>
                        <option name="ia" value="0.761">IA</option>
                        <option name="triare" value="2.418">Finch Flow</option>
                        <option name="esteiras_usuarios" value="41.210">Esteiras por usuário</option>
                        <option name="esteiras_processos" value="1.628">Esteiras por processo</option>
                        <option name="publicacoes" value="0.426">BPO Publicações</option>
                        <option name="cadastro" value="2.02">BPO Cadastro</option>
                        <option name="oficios" value="5.98">BPO Ofícios</option>
                </select>
        </span>
</form>
</div>


label a ser alterada

<div class="c_unit">
    <label>Custo Unitário: <b class="custo_un">R$</b><label class="vlr_tab_serv" name="serv_selecionado"><b class="custo_un" id="valor" value="">**0,00**</b></label></label>
</div>
```

Comment: show de bola, obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Feito! que bom que resolveu! :) Abraço

Answer (score 0):

É possível capturar o `value` do `option` selecionado através do evento `change` do `select`.

Primeiramente eu seleciono o elemento e armazeno dentro de uma variavel

```
let list = document.querySelector("#lista_servicos")
```

Depois basta adicionar um `listener` para o evento `change`

```
list.addEventListener("change", e=>{            
    document.querySelector("#price").innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

observe que os dados do evento são passados como parâmetro para a função, de modo que se você fizer um `console.log(e)` verá os dados do evento no console, entre essas informações podemos capturar o valor do `option` selecionado e atribuir esse valor para a `label`.

fiz uma pequena alteração no seu html, adicionando o id price, no geral sua label ficará dessa forma:

```
<label>Custo Unitário: <b class="custo_un">R$</b><label class="vlr_tab_serv" name="serv_selecionado"><b class="custo_un" id="price" value="">**0,00**</b></label></label>
```

**codigo completo**

```js
let list = document.querySelector("#lista_servicos")
    
        list.addEventListener("change", e=>{            
            document.querySelector("#price").innerHTML = e.target.value

        })
```

```html
<div class="lista_serv">
        <form action="">
            <span>
                <label>Selecione o produto | serviço:</label> 
                    <select class="form-control" id="lista_servicos">
                            <option name="selecione" value="0">Selecione</option> 
                            <option name="gracco" value="49.55">XGracco</option>
                            <option name="automacao" value="0.051">Automação</option>
                            <option name="ia" value="0.761">IA</option>
                            <option name="triare" value="2.418">Finch Flow</option>
                            <option name="esteiras_usuarios" value="41.210">Esteiras por usuário</option>
                            <option name="esteiras_processos" value="1.628">Esteiras por processo</option>
                            <option name="publicacoes" value="0.426">BPO Publicações</option>
                            <option name="cadastro" value="2.02">BPO Cadastro</option>
                            <option name="oficios" value="5.98">BPO Ofícios</option>
                    </select>
            </span>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    
    label a ser alterada
    
    <div class="c_unit">
        <label>Custo Unitário: <b class="custo_un">R$</b><label class="vlr_tab_serv" name="serv_selecionado"><b class="custo_un" id="price" value="">**0,00**</b></label></label>
    </div>
```